# How do I allow multiple monetary display formats on the same installation?

Tags: localisation, currency

I'm trying to duplicate a donation form in two different languages, Canadian French and English. I have the correct languages installed with i18n Internationalisation and translation is working based on the language inherited from Drupal 7. There is only one currency required, CAD.

Money and date formats differ between Canadian English and French, however. The cheat sheet here outlines the settings I want, but I only need it for a single page.

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC41/French+Canadian+localization+settings

As far as I can tell, the localization settings at civicrm/admin/setting/localization?reset=1 apply to the entire site and won't switch with the language. I have made numerous jQuery functions in my Main.tpl, OnBehalfOf.tpl and BillingBlock.tpl override templates to perfect the colloquial wording in various sections, but the money format also needs to change dynamically. This is an example:

$1,000.00 === 1 000,00 $

Is there must be a better way to run a bilingual site? Can you override the localization settings for a single page?

Comment: I believe @samuelsov was working on this very issue for CiviCRM 4.7 during the CiviCRM code sprint last May.

Comment: Did this get resolved?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an extension that might help a bit with money formatting issues in Canada:

https://civicrm.org/extensions/canadianbacon

It basically sets the CiviCRM money settings dynamically when it detects the `fr_CA` or `fr_FR` language. We have been using these kind of hacks for a while, but had never bothered to make a proper extension, hoping it would be fixed in core (which is more complicated to fix than expected).